# How can I branch a string type and a literal type?

Tags: typescript

I want to make a branch when type is "foo", but I get an error. How can I solve this?

```js
type T =
  | {
      type: string;
    }
  | {
      type: "foo";
      bar: number;
    };

const func = (foo: T) => {
  if (foo.type === "foo") {
    // Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'T'.
  // Property 'bar' does not exist on type '{ type: string; }'.
    return foo.bar
  }
}
```

Comment: `foo` can be just `{type:"foo"}` and still conform to type `T` by conforming to `{type:string}`, so `bar` does not necessarily exists.

Comment: In your case, `bar` exists implies `type == "foo"`. But `type == "foo"` does not imply `bar` exists.

Comment: Oh, I see." Is it possible to express a string type other than "foo"?

Comment: No, you can't have a type like "any string other than `'foo'`". Either change your test to something like `if('bar' in foo)`, or write a [type predicate function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), or add a true [discriminant](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) property.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.